# useState hook behaves differently than expected

Tags: reactjs, use-state, i18next, react-i18next

I have a simple language selector (en, cs) in my React app using i18next. The change of the language (applying all the translations and re-rendering the app) takes around 2 seconds.

In the meantime, I want to display a loader, but that doesn't seem to work as expected.

I have two scenarios. The first one does not display `Loader`:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
const [language, setLanguage] = useState(userPreferences.lang);

const handleChangeLanguage = (lang) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setLanguage(lang);
} 

useEffect(() => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(language).then(() => setIsLoading(false) );
},[language])

return (
    <>
        {isLoading ? <Loader /> : <div>lang selector here</div> }
    </>
)
```

But when I use setTimeout (even with zero time) on `setLanguage` the loader is displayed until the lang changes:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
const [language, setLanguage] = useState(userPreferences.lang);

const handleChangeLanguage = (lang) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => setLanguage(lang), 0);    // <= change here
} 

useEffect(() => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(language).then(() => setIsLoading(false) );
},[language])

return (
    <>
        {isLoading ? <Loader /> : <div>lang selector here</div> }
    </>
)
```

Why does it behave like that, and can I set it somehow to avoid `setTimeout`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this code instead of your function and remove useEffect

```
const handleChangeLanguage = async(lang) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
      try {
     const res = await i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
    setIsLoading(false)
        } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    setIsLoading(false)
       }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that does not show the loader either. My first code works well, but I am curious why the setTimeout is necessary there and if there is a nicer solution

Answer (score -2):

Try using `setImmediate()` instead of `setTimeout()`

Comment: not sure how that would help plus there is a warning on MDN for that: "Non-standard: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."